# How to search in multiple xspf files in one folder?

Tags: search

On Windows is this possible?
There are a couple xspf playlists files in a folder.
How to search for a specific track?
Giving only a part of track name as search item

Thanks

Comment: What has your research shown so far? Where did it fail? What OS are you on?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.